# spark join: parenthesis issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am joining two RDDs.

sample file1 data:

```
245216  123422,187,235,742,1635,5600,2782,52,140943
```

sample file2 data:

```
281216  12433,308,454,27862,2693,4578,138812,567,20,716
```

Now here is the code:

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile("file1").map(_.split("\t")).map(line => (line(0), line(1)))
rdd2 = sc.textFile("file2").map(_.split("\t")).map(line => (line(0), line(1)))
val merged = rdd1.join(rdd2)
```

The o/p is k, (v) and I would like to eliminate the parenthesis around the value when doing further processing. I tried a few things including

```
val merged_no_paren = merged.map { case (k, (v)) => (k, v) }
```

I also save the result:

```
 merged_no_paren.map{case x=>s"${x._1}\t${x._2}"}.saveAsTextFile("merged")
```

Unfortunately, the result is always in the following format:

```
100   (1,50,200)
120   (2,25,789)
....
```

I would like them as:

```
100   1,50,200
120   2,25,789
```

Comment: give us the input for rdd1 and rdd2

Comment: Just updated the question with that information.

Comment: what are you joining on?

Comment: This `join` cannot work - please post the code you actually use.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RDD after joining is of type `RDD[(String, (String, String))]`. If you just print a `(String, String)`, it prints with parentheses. But you can take it apart and print it any way you like.

```
scala> val s = Seq(("1", ("2", "3")))
s: Seq[(String, (String, String))] = List((1,(2,3)))

scala> for (e <- s) println(e)
(1,(2,3))

scala> for ((k, v) <- s) println(s"$k $v")
1 (2,3)

scala> for ((k, (v1, v2)) <- s) println(s"$k $v1,$v2")
1 2,3
```